# How to set the type of account for custom MAPI Message Service

Tags: outlook, mapi

How to set the type of account for custom MAPI message service in "email" tab in Outlook? I mean how to change word "MAPI" for something else (please see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create your own MAPI provider? Why exactly do you want to change it?

Comment: Yes I am. Because I have requirements to inform user about the type of account in that window.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for creating non-MAPI providers (such as POP3/SMTP built-in provider). Outlook knowns about some accounts, both MAPI (PST or Exchange) and non-MAPI (POP3/SMTP or IMAP4/SMTP), but there is no way to make it know anything about your custom provider.